# can we have wordpress table name with more than 2 underscore

Tags: wordpress

I was renaming my all the tables. So i just want to confirm that can there be more than 2 underscore(_) in a table name.

> Ex: (wp_sum_2_options)

Is this acceptable

Comment: you can have more than 2 underscores (EWWW Image Optimizer) uses as well multiple underscores for example.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is no problem using `(_)` for database tables name just i the end put another `(_)`

> Ex: wp_sum_2_options_